# $l(f,P) \leq u(f,Q)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, riemann-sum

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two partitions of $[a,b]$ and $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that $l(f,P) \leq u(f,Q)$, where $l(f,P)$ and $u(f,Q)$ denote the lower Darboux sum and the upper Darboux sum respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if we pass to the common refinement $P\cup Q$,we have

$l(f,P) \le l(f,P\cup Q)$

$l(f,P\cup Q)\le u(f,P \cup Q)$ and

$u(f,P \cup Q)\le u(f,Q).$

The first and third inequality are true by direct calculation. (First add one point to $P$, and relate $\min f$ and $\max f$ on the two new subintervals,to the original one. The result follows by induction). The second inequality is a triviality.

Combining these, we have

$l(f,P) \le l(f,P\cup Q) \le u(f,P \cup Q) \le u(f,Q).$

Comment: Could you elaborate why the third inequality  is true?

Comment: hint: add one point, $c$, to the partition, so that $x_i<c<x_{i+1}$ and then relate max$f$ and min$f$ on $[x_i,c],[c,x_{i+1}] $ and $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint: show that if $P$ and $Q$ are two partitions and $P \subset Q$ (interpreting a partition as a finite subset of $[a,b]$) then $l(f,P) \le l(f,Q)$ and $u(f,Q) \le u(f,P)$.

Then
$$l(f,P) \le l(f,P\cup Q) \le u(f,P \cup Q) \le u(f,Q).$$

Comment: This is not quite right. P and Q could very well be disjoint, and the inequalities are still true.

Comment: @Chilango, his hint is too good, think a little.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi: I thought he was using the $P$ and $Q$ of the OP's question. If it's a hint indicating that one must pass  to the common refinement, so that $P\subseteq P\cup Q$ and $Q\subseteq P\cup Q$,then it's fine.

Comment: it is precisely this!